# Doctrine2 How to check if there is the related record in

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a bidirectional many-to-many between theese two entities:

### Position

```
/**
* Position
*
* @ORM\Table(name="applypie_position")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Applypie\Bundle\PositionBundle\Entity\PositionRepository")
*/
class Position
{

const IS_ACTIVE = true;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Applypie\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Applicant", mappedBy="bookmarks")
 */
private $bookmarkedApplicants;
```

### Applicant

```
/**
 * Applicant
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="applypie_applicant")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Applicant
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Applypie\Bundle\PositionBundle\Entity\Position", inversedBy="bookmarkedApplicants")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="applypie_user_job_bookmarks",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="applicant_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="position_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $bookmarks;
```

My Problem is: In an PositionControllers Action which easily shows an position by ID i need to know if there the current Applicant whichs wants to see the position has an bookmark for the current position.

I first thought of get all the Bookmarks with $applicant->getBookmarks() and run in within a forearch, checking all the applicants bookmarks against the current position, but i think there must be an easier way?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay object oriented you can do it this way:

```
class Applicant
{
    // fields and ORM annotations

    public function hasBookmark(Bookmark $bookmark) {
        return $this->bookmarks->contains($bookmark);
    }



class MyController
{
    public function testAction() {
        $applicant = $this->getUser(); // or however you fetch the applicant object
        $bookmark  = $bookmarkRepository->find($bookmarkId); // again, however you get the bookmark object

        // @var boolean $applicantHasBookmark
        $applicantHasBookmark = $applicant->hasBookmark($bookmark);

        // other controller code
    }
```